# How do I data bind to a union case value within XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml, f#

How do I data bind to a union case value within XAML?

Currently the data-bound value is pointing to the String20 object instead of the actual string value that the union case (i.e. String20) wraps around.

**Example:**

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Modules}" DisplayMemberPath="Author.First" />
```

**Author Definition:**

```
type Name = { 
    First:String20
    Last:String20
    Suffix:String20 option 
}

type Module = { 
    Author:Name
    Duration:Duration 
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="Client.MainWindow"
        ...
        xmlns:manageModules="clr-namespace:ManageModules;assembly=ManageModules">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <manageModules:CreationViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Grid>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Modules}" DisplayMemberPath="Author.First" 
                  TextElement.Foreground="LightBlue" Background="Black" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**ViewModel:**

```
namespace ManageModules
    ...
    type CreationViewModel() =
        inherit ViewModelBase()
        let name =      { First=String20("Scott"); Last=String20("Nimrod"); Suffix=None }
        let duration =  { Hours=1; Minutes=30; Seconds=0 }
        let moduleItem = { Author=name; Duration=duration }

        let mutable (_modules:Module ObservableCollection) = ObservableCollection()

        do _modules.Add(moduleItem)

        member this.Modules
            with get()      = _modules
            and set(value)  = _modules <- value

        member this.Add moduleItem = 
            _modules.Add(moduleItem)
```

**Business Domain:**

```
module ManageModule.Entities

type Duration = { 
    Hours:int
    Minutes:int
    Seconds:int 
}

type String20 = String20 of string

type Name = { 
    First:String20
    Last:String20
    Suffix:String20 option 
}

type Module = { 
    Author:Name
    Duration:Duration 
}

and Section = 
    | Introduction of Module
    | Conclusion of Module
    | Content of Module list
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My recommendation would be to modify `String20` so that it includes an additional member that is a plain `string` value - and then you can bind to the ordinary `string` member.

To add member to a type, you can write:

```
type String20 = 
  | String20 of string
  member this.Value = 
    let (String20(str)) = this
    str
```

Then you should be able to write:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Modules}" DisplayMemberPath="Author.First.Value" />
```

There are probably more sophisticated ways to solve this - I guess WPF has some mechanism for specifying transformations that happen in bindings behind the scenes - but adding `Value` as a member is probably a good simple start.

Answer (score 0):

**Another approach is to use a ValueConverter as Tomas was alluding to.**

This example is written in C#. Later, when I find more time, I will demonstrate the same approach using F#.

I prefer to preserve simplicity within the domain logic and NOT let UI or data store frameworks dictate (i.e. take hostage) the domain logic.

**As a result, I have provided the following value converter using C#:**

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows.Data;
using static ManageModule.Entities;

namespace Client.Converters
{
    public class String20Converter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var unionCase = value as String20;
            return unionCase.Item;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

**The updated XAML looks like this:**

```
<Window x:Class="Client.MainWindow"
        ...
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Client"
        xmlns:manageModules="clr-namespace:ManageModules;assembly=ManageModules"
        xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:Client.Converters"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Background="Black"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <manageModules:CreationViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Window.Resources>
        <converters:String20Converter x:Key="String20Converter" />
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Modules}" Background="Black">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Author.First, Converter={StaticResource String20Converter}}"
                               Foreground="LightBlue" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Note how we can preserve our original domain logic:**

```
type Duration = { 
    Hours:int
    Minutes:int
    Seconds:int 
}

type String20 = String20 of string

type Name = { 
    First:String20
    Last:String20
    Suffix:String2
}
```